# Copy image to ROI

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm trying to copy one image to another and I use CopyTo to achieve it, except instead of the source image being put in the ROI of the target, my target image gets replaced entirely.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var output = new Mat(size, size, MatType.CV_8UC3, background);
var temp1 = image.Resize(new OpenCvSharp.Size(targetWidth, targetHeight), 0, 0, interpolation);
xOffset = Convert.ToInt32((size - targetWidth) / 2);
yOffset = Convert.ToInt32((size - targetHeight) / 2);
output.AdjustROI(yOffset, (size - 1) - yOffset, xOffset, (size - 1) - xOffset);
temp1.CopyTo(output);
output.AdjustROI(0, size - 1, 0, size - 1);
```

I found that in OpenCV this is now achieved by using `()` operator with ROI, however I cannot find this operator in OpenCVSharp and I have no clue what it's equivalent might be named like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that this might be achieved using `Mat`'s constructor in OpenCVSharp and the following code seems to do the trick:

```
var output = new Mat(size, size, MatType.CV_8UC3, background);
var temp1 = image.Resize(new OpenCvSharp.Size(targetWidth, targetHeight), 0, 0, interpolation);
xOffset = Convert.ToInt32((size - targetWidth) / 2);
yOffset = Convert.ToInt32((size - targetHeight) / 2);
var roi = new Mat(output, new Rect(xOffset, yOffset, targetWidth, targetHeight));
temp1.CopyTo(roi);
```

Comment: You did well to find this version of the Mat constructor! As you say it returns a Mat with a different header but the **same** image data - I was struggling with this exact same issue and your solution works. Many thanks!